# How to pass a function variable to a Boostrap UI modal?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I need to pass a variable to my modal when clicking on the open button. I'd like to do it with the angular bootstrap ui modal. I need this because I will use a reusable modal for each page, and depending on the page I want to change the content of the modal.

I named my variable 'x' for the example.

Here is the code I'm working on :

On the second alert, the object is null, if anyone has a solution, even with an other modal 'coding style', I would be grateful :)

Script :

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

     $scope.open = function (x) {
         var modalInstance = $modal.open({
             templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
             controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
             resolve: {
                 x: function () {
                     return $scope.x;
                 }
             }
         });
         alert(x);
     };
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, x) {
    alert(x);
    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};
```

HTML :

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            {{ x }}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        </script>

        <button class="btn" ng-click="open('x')">Open</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never stored the variable 'x' in the $scope. 
I fixed your example - see here on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/76mMaChGISPcwZTkttOD?p=preview)

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

   $scope.open = function (x) {
     var modalInstance = $modal.open({
         templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
         controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
         resolve: {
             x: function () {
                 return x; // <-- just use the function parameter
             }
         }
     });
   };
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, x) {
    $scope.x = x; // store x in the scope
    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};
```

Comment: Do you know why this variable doesn't need the $scope ? Well, thank you for your help so much !

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this? Of course the variable must be stored in $scope to show it in the modal. But you have to store it there yourself, Angular doesn't do it for you.

But you can simplify the modalInstance and avoid using 'resolve' and use the scope inheritance instead.http://plnkr.co/edit/76mMaChGISPcwZTkttOD?p=preview

Comment: Ah ok I thought the variable was already in the scope of the first controller when you pass it through the function ! Thank you for your improvement, could be easier to use this instead of the resolve...